# Duplicate question already answered?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, duplicate-suggestions

What should I do if I answer a duplicate question and the answer is accepted?

Soon after answering I noticed that the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810905/history-across-ipdb-sessions/40745331#40745331) is a duplicate post, but it hasn't been deleted in 2 years, so, now that my answer has been accepted and flagged as best one, should I flag the post as duplicate, wait for deletion, and then post the answer in the [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138106/ipython-ipdb-when-invoked-via-ipdb-set-trace-does-not-remember-the-command-h?noredirect=1&lq=1) topic?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the part,  *flagged as best one should I flag the post as duplicate...* I think the question starts with "should" and can you edit your question? Also, please include the links for reference. It could be better if you asked this question on the relevant Meta site.

Comment: @Rathony: thanks for the feedback, I edited the question with the hope that it will be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no rules set in stone for this, so I'll share my views.

Duplicates are not that bad to have around, and questions closed as duplicates are usually **not** deleted (unless they have negative score and no answers, in which case [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) deletes them).

Also, with duplicates, the only relevant thing that affects the decision which to close as dupe is **the quality of the answers already posted**. That means, if you truly believe the answers on a question, whether it includes your own answer or not, are better than the answers on the original, older, question (or if that older question got no answers at all) then by all means - flag to vote that older question as duplicate of the new question.

If the older question does contain better answers flag the question you answered as duplicate of it. The fact you, or someone else, posted an answer already is not relevant. The answer(s) will still be there, and cause no harm.

Having the answer accepted is also not really relevant. It only means it solved the specific issue OP was having. No need to delete anything or flag any answer.

Comment: This applies also if the original (older) question doesn't have a concluding answer yet?

Comment: @MicheleSr see edit.